# How to transfer posts from an existing blog platform to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a project where I need to transfer blog post data from a existing blog website which I don't have admin access, to a new WordPress platform that I created. I would like to do that automatically since there are hundreds of posts with text and pictures. Is there anyway to do that with a script or some kind of a WordPress plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress can import any type of content from xml file, with a correct structure, So you can create an xml file from your blog database, and make it compatible with wordpress, for example:

```
<item>
    <title>El solar de los ciruelos</title>
    <link>http://www.elescritorapestado.com/probetes/el-solar-de-los-ciruelos</link>
    <pubDate>Sun, 09 Feb 2014 22:37:36 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[memoadian]]></dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.elescritorapestado.com/?p=96</guid>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<div style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;text-align:justify">
         No puedo dejar de pensar en ella.</div>]]>
    </content:encoded>
    <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
    <wp:post_id>96</wp:post_id>
    <wp:post_date><![CDATA[2014-02-09 22:37:36]]></wp:post_date>
    <wp:post_date_gmt><![CDATA[2014-02-09 22:37:36]]></wp:post_date_gmt>
    <wp:comment_status><![CDATA[open]]></wp:comment_status>
    <wp:ping_status><![CDATA[open]]></wp:ping_status>
    <wp:post_name><![CDATA[el-solar-de-los-ciruelos]]></wp:post_name>
    <wp:status><![CDATA[publish]]></wp:status>
    <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
    <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
    <wp:post_type><![CDATA[post]]></wp:post_type>
    <wp:post_password><![CDATA[]]></wp:post_password>
    <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    <category domain="category" nicename="probetes"><![CDATA[Probetes]]></category>
    <wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_edit_last]]></wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
</item>
```

Yo can export any posts from any Wordpress site and copy the file structure.